Is it possible to edit a grease pencil's opacity/alpha through shaders or geometry nodes?
I want to create an effect where lineart fades away the further it gets from the camera. I have that camera distance value in geonodes already thanks to 4.3's screen space sizing workaround node, but I can't work out how to use that to fade the lineart.
The best I have been able to do so far is use the Z depth of the scene to multiply with the grease pencil in the compositor, but this isn't a perfect method as that crops the lineart to the edges of objects.

You could store the distance to camera in an GN attribute and then use that in the shader. That's if the CameraData node in the Shader Editor isn't enough for you.

I don't think you can use nodes with grease pencil though.
